# How to make REST API using ODA (OpenNTF Domino API)?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Like in title how to make a REST API using ODA?
I am trying to find it in official documentation but i failed :(

Does solution using ODA exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ODA as such isn't a toolset for making REST APIs. It has a ".rest" plugin, but that's specifically about exposing a Graph API via JAX-RS.

That leads to the remaining main options:

- The Extension Library has a JSON REST service control that helps a bit with building a service.
- You could use the "XAgent" approach to grab the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` to handle it yourself. That's the fiddliest approach and I don't recommend it.
- You could write an OSGi plugin that uses JAX-RS to expose REST services: https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/2015/12/3/1CD1740C77996C8B85257F10006FEB21 . This one offers the best balance of a good experience with available documentation
- You could use the XPages Jakarta EE Support project to use JAX-RS within your NSF: https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.xsp.jakartaee . This is a great developer experience but has few active users beyond me personally.
- You could use SmartNSF to generate your APIs: https://smartnsf.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/SmartNSF . This doesn't use JAX-RS, but instead uses an in-NSF Groovy DSL descriptor with a bunch of helper classes to accomplish common tasks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [ODA Starter Servlet](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API%20Starter%20Servlet).

Fair warning:
- the development is done in Eclipse, outside of the NSF.
- it's best done with Maven, so you'll need to get to install and use Maven. The documentation covers the basics.
- I wrote it, it's stable and in use in production at customers. But I'm now at HCL and not actively using it.

Answer (score 0):

Tagging onto Jesse's response here is a demo/slides of two ways to do REST, one using the XAgent approach and one with the Jakarka EE approach. This was a presentation Jesse and I did at Collabsphere.
https://bitbucket.org/howardtlcc-admin/collabsphere-2019-dev112/src/master/